# Keeping unique, non-repetitive rows in a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

My `cor_test()` call produces lots of repetitive output. For example, `mpg cyl` is really the same as `cyl mpg`. Also, I want correlation of any variable with itself (ex. `mpg mpg`) to be eliminated throughout.

Can we limit the output to only unique, non-repetitive rows?

(*Note:* This is a toy example. A functional answer is appreciated.)

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% cor_test(mpg:disp)

1 mpg   mpg    1       Inf    0.          1         1     Pearson  
2 mpg   cyl   -0.85     -8.92 6.11e-10   -0.926    -0.716 Pearson  #
3 mpg   disp  -0.85     -8.75 9.38e-10   -0.923    -0.708 Pearson
4 cyl   mpg   -0.85     -8.92 6.11e-10   -0.926    -0.716 Pearson  #
5 cyl   cyl    1       Inf    0.          1         1     Pearson  
6 cyl   disp   0.9      11.4  1.80e-12    0.807     0.951 Pearson  
7 disp  mpg   -0.85     -8.75 9.38e-10   -0.923    -0.708 Pearson
8 disp  cyl    0.9      11.4  1.80e-12    0.807     0.951 Pearson
9 disp  disp   1       Inf    0.          1         1     Pearson
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pmin`/`pmax` to sort the columns and then use `distinct` to keep only unique rows. We can write a function for that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

delete_duplicates <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    filter(var1 != var2) %>%
    mutate(col1 = pmin(var1, var2),
           col2 = pmax(var1, var2)) %>%
    distinct(col1, col2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    select(-col1, -col2)
}
```

and pass it to `cor_test` output.

```
mtcars %>% 
  cor_test(mpg:disp) %>%
  delete_duplicates()


#  var1  var2    cor statistic        p conf.low conf.high method 
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
#1 mpg   cyl   -0.85     -8.92 6.11e-10   -0.926    -0.716 Pearson
#2 mpg   disp  -0.85     -8.75 9.38e-10   -0.923    -0.708 Pearson
#3 cyl   disp   0.9      11.4  1.80e-12    0.807     0.951 Pearson
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
out <- cor_test(subset(mtcars, select = mpg:disp))
out[!duplicated(t(apply(out[c('var1', 'var2')], 1, sort))) & 
         out$var1 != out$var2,]
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  var1  var2    cor statistic        p conf.low conf.high method 
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
#1 mpg   cyl   -0.85     -8.92 6.11e-10   -0.926    -0.716 Pearson
#2 mpg   disp  -0.85     -8.75 9.38e-10   -0.923    -0.708 Pearson
#3 cyl   disp   0.9      11.4  1.80e-12    0.807     0.951 Pearson
```